# Status 200 = HttpPut works?

Tags: php, android, mysql, slim

I'm trying to modify a value of my database (`MySQL`). For this issue I'm using `HttPut` on my `Android` application and `Slim framework` as micro framework of PHP with `XAMPP` for managing the database.

The problem it's that it doesn't modify my database but it gives to me the status 200 when I use `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`.

And if I didn't understood it, when you receive an status 200 it's because the request had been succesful. As you can see here: [status 200 OK](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> The request has succeeded.

Am I missing something? Did I understand it wrong? Why it could be that the database doesn't change?

**P.S.** If you need that I provide some code, just let me know in a comment.

**EDIT:** Here it's my `put` method in my `PHP script`.

```
$app->put("/cars/",function() use($app)
{
    $name = $app->request->put("name");
    $description = $app->request->put("description");
    $idCar = $app->request->put("idCar");

    try{
        $connection = getConnection();
        $dbh = $connection->prepare("UPDATE cars SET name = ?, description = ? WHERE idCar = ?");
        $dbh->bindParam(1,$name);
        $dbh->bindParam(2,$description);
        $dbh->bindParam(3,$idCar);

        $dbh->execute();
        $connection = null;

        header("HTTP/1.1 200");
        header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode(array('status' => true),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

EDIT 2: Here it's the code in which I use `HttpPut`.

```
class EditCar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private Car editCar;

    EditCar(Car editCar) {
        this.editCar = editCar;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            String url = "http://IP of my computer/project/cars/";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut method = new HttpPut(url);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", editCar.getName()));
            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", editCar.getDescription()));
            nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idCar", Integer.toString(editCar.getIdCar())));

            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", ex.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the php code? Also, depending on what headers you set (*if any*), if it found and ran the php file it'd return 200 OK. Also, try putting PHP error reporting on by putting this at the top of your script - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: @Darren For sure, I will edit now my question with my `put` method. And where I have to place your `ini_set` and `error_reporting`? Before all my methods?

Comment: Yeah the very first thing after your `<?php` opening tag.

Comment: `UPDATE` won't return a `$connection->lastInsertId()` as nothing was inserted, that may cause an issue (*the returned json would be empty.*). What exactly do you need to return to your app?

Comment: @Darren I didn't have it before but if not, I don't know what I have to put on `echo json_encode(//here,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: You could return something like `echo json_encode(array('status' => true), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`. and if it failed (*in your catch*), you could set status to `false` and check in your app to apply accordingly.

Comment: @Darren I'm really new on PHP (just my first contact with it in this app) and maybe it is a basic question but with `echo json_encode` I send a message to the application, right? And if it is true, how can I see it on the app?

Comment: Yes that is correct Error, it'll send the json back to your app. I'm unfamiliar with programming for Android (*java is it?*). You'd just get it from the response, which seems to be something like `response = thing.execute(otherthing);` - [A Google search like this perhaps?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=HttPut+on+Android+get+response)

Comment: @Darren Yes, my response it's using `.execute` but when I use `response.toString();` I get `org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@` and a serie of numbers. It's what I mean before, the response I know how to get it, but not the message that I send :S

Comment: Could you show that code?

Comment: @Darren Do you mean the code in which I use HttpPut?

Comment: Yes thats the code I'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. I didn't know how to see what data was being used on my application on my `HttpPut` method, so by searching on the Internet finally I found a method to see what data was being used. It's the following:

After executing your response, you can put this two lines:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

And then you can see what data it's being sent in your `HttpPut` with a `Log`:

```
Log.d("response",responseText);
```

With that method I saw the array that were sending and also it gave to me an error in which it said to me that I `cannot add or update a child row`. It is because `$idCar` have a reference (in cascade) in another table and I was sending a value that doesn't exist on that other table.

When I send a value that exists in the second table it works properly!

**EDIT:** To see the array of the values that you are using you have to put

```
print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]);
```

on your `php script` inside your put method and after setting your variables values. Like this:

```
$name = $app->request->put("name");
$description = $app->request->put("description");
$idCar = $app->request->put("idCar");

print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 200 status says nothing about your update.

- Do you choose the right database connection?
- Your query looks normal, but I can't see the parameter values. Are you sure that they contains the right values?
- You can specify the data type the bindParam method
- You do 'update', so lastInsertId is for 'insert'

But, you can do this:

```
print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]); // temporaly line for debugging!

$dbh = $connection->prepare("UPDATE cars SET name = ?, description = ? WHERE idCar = ?");
$dbh->execute([$name,$description,$idCar]);
```

If you use < PHP 5.4: [] must be array()

Comment: Now I edited my question of the issue of `lastInsertId` and I know that the connection database it's right because I use `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` methods and I don't have any problem. What do you want to see when you say `parameter values`? What I send to the query?

Comment: Yes, are you sure that each parameter variable has the right value?

Comment: When I add them to `nameValuePairList` I have to convert them to `String` (because it doesn't accept other type of value). Have I to convert again on php script?

Comment: Let's check this first: what's the output if you do: print_r([$name,$description,$idCar]);

Comment: Where I have to put it? On my php script?

Comment: And where it is printed? How can I access to it from my Android app?